# Only put a certain number of lines in a char array

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, char

I have a file with 2939 lines, and I am trying to save the five lines together in one index of a 2D char array.
So,

```
 char [][] myArray;
 myArray[0] = {} //<--char array of first five lines
 myArray[1]= //char array of next five lines
```

the way I am implementing this is:

```
int countLines=0; 
while (sc.hasNext() countLines <5) { //sc is scanner
   //read each line and append to a string builder
   //then convert stringbuilder to char array and
   //store in myArray[0]

   countLines++;
 }
```

I am stuck on the part of storing the next five lines in myArray[1]. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As line number is unknown, so use ArrayList instead of array.

Comment: Why do you want to use a char array? How doesn't a List<String> suit your needs?

Comment: Why not use a `String`?

Comment: @masud sorry, i realized i know the line number. its 2939.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    if(countLines < 5) {
        //store in myArray[0]
    } else if(countLines >= 5 && countLines < 10) {
        //store in myArray[1]
    }
    countLines++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer using Lists instead of arrays:

```
    List<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
       myArray.add(sc.nextLine());
    }
    // your 5 first line:
    // your 5 first line array:
    List<String> fiveLines = myArray.subList(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

use array list they since you dont know size of array

```
 ArrayList<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

now add as

```
 strs.add("your string");
```

get size

```
strs.size();
```